# Rotation Matrix with local control?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, 3d, rotations

Is there a rotation matrix that provides local control at each axis? I'm not entirely sure how to phrase what I'm asking - the best analogy I can give is imagining taking a physical version of the basis vectors, then literally holding and twisting around one axis, then grabbing and twisting around a second axis (sorry for not being well-versed in linear algebra jargon). Almost like I independently twist the axes themselves, but then somehow combine the results (I also don't want it to be a multistep process - just one matrix, if thats even possible).

All rotation matrices I've found only have that kind of local control at 1 axis, and it's just dependent on the order in which the basis rotation matrices are multiplied. I even tried to derive it myself and got rather close to the behavior I want, but I messed it up and can't trace my error (if you want to see what I did, let me know).

Sorry if this isn't a "good" question, I've just spend the entire day confused with rotation matrices and angles, and wanted to see what actually smart people had to say about it.

**EDIT:** I found what I was looking for in quaternions, sorry y'all!

Comment: Why is that kind of local control at one axis insufficient?

Comment: Whenever I start off with 1 axis at a non-zero angle. If I want to rotate about, say the *resulting* z-axis after rotating the y-axis, it never keeps the z-axis still, instead rotating about the global z-axis

Comment: Uh, yea, but what does my username have to do with it?

Comment: @ChemistCraft300 I hypothesised that the question stems from theoretical chemistry.

Comment: I wish I was that advanced in my life, but alas, I am merely a woefully confused high schooler who came up with their online alias when they were 7 and hasn't changed it since.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to have in particular a "fine control" over the axes is to use the exponential formalism.

Precisely, a rotation matrix defined by angle $\theta$ around axis defined by **unit** vector $\vec{a}=(a_x,a_y,a_z)$ can be expressed in this way :

$$R_{\theta,\vec{a}}=\exp(\theta A)$$

where $A$ is the skew-symmetric matrix

$$A:=\begin{pmatrix}0&-a_z&a_y\\a_z&0&-a_x\\-a_y&a_x&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Of course, you need for your computations to use a software that computes the matrix exponential for you ; Matlab, Python, Mathematica Maple, etc. have a built-in function (matrix) exponential.

This matrix $A$ is often denoted $[a]_{\times}$ because of its connection with cross product $\times$ ; indeed, $[a]_{\times}$ applied to a vector $v$ gives the cross product $a \times v$, as can be seen here :

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&-a_z&a_y\\a_z&0&-a_x\\-a_y&a_x&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a_yz-a_zy\\a_zx-a_xz\\a_xy-a_yx\end{pmatrix}$$

The fact that cross product is involved in rotation issues shouldn't be a surprise...

By progressive *leftwise* multiplication (remembering that they do not commute and that all $a_i$ are **unit** vectors),

$$\cdots R_{\theta_3,\vec{a_3}} \ R_{\theta_2,\vec{a_2} } \ R_{\theta_1,\vec{a_1}}$$

you should be able to "tune" the rotation you desire to achieve.

Here is for example a Matlab code showing the effectiveness of the procedure, knowing that expm and logm are the matrix function exponential and logarithm :

```
 clear all;
 cro=@(t,a,b,c)(expm(t*([0,-c,b;c,0,-a;-b,a,0]))
 R1=cro(pi/2,1,0,1);
 R2=cro(pi/2,0,1,0);
 R3=cro(-pi/2,1,0,0);
 P=R3*R2*R1;% identical to cro(-pi/2,0,0,1) 
 % which is the pi/2 rot. around z axis ; indeed :
 L=logm(P);
 A=[L(3,2),L(1,3),L(2,1)]; % (non unit) vector giving rotation axis 
 t=norm(A), % rotation angle
 A/t, % (normalized) vector giving rotation axis.
```

Comment: This is interesting, how/why does it work?

Comment: You can understand it as a generalization 2D $\to$ 3D of the rotation with angle $\theta$ :  $z \to e^{i \theta}z$ (multiplication by $e^{i \theta}$ of complex number $z$). This is well explained [here](https://www.math.umd.edu/~immortal/MATH401/book/ch_exponentials_and_rotations.pdf).

Comment: Ohh, will I have to recompute all of the matrices every time I want to update an angle? Is there no way to turn them into functions of $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, and $\theta_3$? Because if I computed all of the matrices for the basis vectors then multiplied them together, I get back to the same problem again of not having local control over all axes.

Comment: The local control is the fact that having a first guess on one of them, then comes the improvement by slightly modifying the angle and the rotation axis by a small increment on angle and axis
$R_{\theta_2+\Delta\theta_2,\vec{a_2}+\Delta \vec{a_2} } \approx \underbrace{R_{\Delta\theta_2,\Delta \vec{a_2} }}_{improvement}$ composed with $R_{\theta_2,\vec{a_2}}$

Comment: Guesses? I'm not sure I follow...
I dont think we are using the same definition of "local control", sorry for being bad at terminology...
What I mean by local control is whenever I make some rotation about some axis, then go to make another rotation, I want it to rotate around where the axis ended up *after* the first rotation. But, I want that information all encapsulated in 1 single matrix with 3 parameters, $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, and $\theta_3$, which I'm not entirely sure is possible?

Comment: Sure it is possible. When you have made successive rotations (i.e., making the different products), some of them being hopefully mere adjustments as said above, resulting in a certain rotation matrix $R$, it is possible to retrieve the corresponding angles and axis (i.e., retrieving the form $R=\exp(\theta A)$ by taking the logarithm of matrix $R$.

Comment: I have added a (Matlab) code example.